# Выполнить асинхронную функцию синхронно

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, asyncio

**Входные данные**:
Я пишу скрипт на python. Метод экземпляра класса из этого скрипта экспортируются в другой файл и помещается внутрь event loop, но этот event loop создаётся не мной, а фреймворком, поэтому я не могу в него впихнуть свою функцию. Код в примере максимально упрощён, а все функции заменены на выдуманные для того, чтобы было легче понять

**Сам скрипт**:

```
""" Импорт функции из одной библиотеки. Эта функция асинхронна и требует await перед собой
Мне необходимо выполнить эту функцию в своём скрипте """
from library import some_function

""" Импорт класса из фреймворка (никак не связано с библиотекой,
отткуда импортируется функция выше).
При запуске всей системы экземпляр этого класса импортируется в другой файл,
который я так же не могу изменять. В этом файле происходит создание и запуск event loop """
from framework import SomeClass

""" Создание экземпляра класса """
someclass = SomeClass()

""" Далее идёт изменение свойств класса и прочий код """
# ...
# ...
# ...

""" Здесь мне нужно выполнить функцию, которая была импортирована из библиотеки ранее НО: """
some_function() # - Ошибка! Функция не имеет await перед собой

await some_function() # - Ошибка! Нельзя использовать await вне функции

import asyncio
asyncio.run(some_function()) # - Ошибка! Вы пытаетесь создать event loop внутри другого event loop
```

Как быть?

Comment: Экземпляр класса `SomeClass` не имеет ссылки - аттрибута на `event loop`? Может, как приватный где-то есть?

Comment: @mkkik Не знаю, проверю и отпишу, сейчас нет возможности

Comment: Кстати, можно и через `asyncio.get_event_loop` попробовать получить.

Comment: @mkkik да, get_event_loop работает, мне удалось добавить свою корутину в event loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была решена таких образом:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(some_function())
```

Answer (score 4):

Видимо, уже нашли решение. Вот для тех, кто ищет:

Используйте `asyncio.get_event_loop()` чтобы получить уже существующий event loop:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(some_function()) # Будет ждать, пока some_function не закончит выполнение.
```

Согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html), `run_until_complete` выполняет async функцию, при этом блокируя исполнение программы в месте вызова. Другими словами, выполняет асинхронную функцию синхронно.

Comment: Это не работает, потому что event loop уже запущен и выбрасывается исключение. Решение я нашёл, чуть позже добавлю

Comment: Понял. Какое исключение?

Comment: Метод `run_until_complete` может быть применён только для event loop, который ещё не запущен или остановлен. Если попытаться применить его к event loop, который уже работает, то будет выброшено исключение, о том, что event loop уже запущен

Comment: @Inventor `await asyncio.ensure_future(coro)`?