# Не могу победить ошибку RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'save_res' was never awaited

Tags: python, asyncio

Имеется неторая струкутура файлов:

```
some_project
│
├───some_files
│   ├───save_res.py
│   ├───some_class_1.py
│   └───some_class_.py
└───
```

some_class_1.py

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class SomeClass1:
    def __init__(self, key=''):
        self.key = key
        print(f'SomeClass1 got {self.key}')
        # описание класса

    async def foo_1(self, url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
            async with s.get(url) as r:
                res =  await r.text()
        return res

    async def foo_2(self, res):
        if res:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print('SomeClass1.foo_2 got the results')
        # некоторые действия
        some_result = [1, 1, 1]
        return some_result

    async def launch(self):
        res = await self.foo_1('https://www.ya.ru')
        next_res = await self.foo_2(res)
        print('SomeClass1 is complete')
        return next_res
```

some_class_2.py

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class SomeClass2:
    def __init__(self, key=''):
        self.key = key
        print(f'SomeClass2 got {self.key}')
        # описание класса

    async def foo_1(self, url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
            async with s.get(url) as r:
                res =  await r.text()
        return res

    async def foo_2(self, res):
        if res:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print('SomeClass2.foo_2 got the results')
        # некоторые действия
        some_result = [2, 2, 2]
        return some_result

    async def launch(self):
        res = await self.foo_1('https://www.ya.ru')
        next_res = await self.foo_2(res)
        print('SomeClass2 is complete')
        return next_res
```

save_res.py

```
import asyncio
from .some_class_1 import SomeClass1
from .some_class_2 import SomeClass2

async def save_res(arg):
    tasks = [
        SomeClass1(arg).launch(),
        SomeClass2(arg).launch()
    ]
    result = []
    res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    for r in res:
        if r:
            result.extend(r)
    print(result)
    # сохранение результата в базу данных
    return
```

some_sync_func.py

```
from some_files.save_res import save_res

def some_sync_func(data):
    arg = data['key']
    save_res(arg)
    # некоторые действия
    return print('All is ok, baddy!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_sync_func({'key':'value'})
```

Вызов функции some_sync_func() вызывает ошибку:

```
C:\some_project\some_sync_func.py:5: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'save_res' was never awaited
  save_res(arg)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
All is ok, baddy!
```

Я понимаю, что запускаю асинхронную функцию из синхронной, но не понимаю как это исправить. Так же интересует как эффективно при помощи какого-нибудь flag остановить выполнение tasks в любой момент. Проблема в том, что сама функция смены flag находится в some_sync_func.py. Можно, к примеру, добавить её в tasks, а в функции launch() классов SomeClass1 и SomeClass2 сделать проверку flag.

Comment: Скорее всего тут решение вашего вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1172601/1365

Comment: @insolor
Это решение вызывает новую проблему
`RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.`

Comment: Значит создать свой event loop или вместо create_task использовать ensure_future - он сам создает event loop при необходимости.

Comment: @insolor, думаю мне стоит накинуть подробностей. Я не опытен, только учусь. Сам по себе пример представляет часть моего кода на django. Функция `some_sync_func() ` представляет собой `view`, которая  запускается посредством ajax запроса на стороне клиента. Код вьюхи синхронный и ему необходимо дождаться пока `some_sync_func() ` выполнится. Я правильно понял, что сама вьюха выполняется в своём потоке и в своём событийном цикле, а асинхронная функция в своём и мне необходимо их как-то "совместить" или же я ошибаюсь и пишу чушь? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это код работает с django,  то https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/#async-to-sync

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
async_to_sync(save_res(arg))
```

У джанги нет событийного цикла если она запущенна на `runserver` или `wsgi`. есть пул тредов и каджый запрос обрабатывается в своем треде. Для совместимости с asyncio сделали модуль `asgiref.sync`

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно помогло. Я использовал декоратор 
`@async_to_sync` для `save_res(arg)`. И получил ясность в некоторых аспектах работы фреймворка